# Utilities to overclock ATI Radeon graphic card

Tags: hardware, ati

Is it possible to overclock my Radeon HD2400 XT graphics card under Ubuntu? Which application is needed? I have the proprietary driver installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the application you are looking for is rovclock.

```
sudo apt-get install rovclock
```

Comment: I've got a message such as: Invalid reference clock from BIOS: 0.0 MHz

Comment: Don't care about it. You can set the frequencies ignoring this message. This seems to be a common problem, and most people affected by it (including me) claim that it can be safely ignored and it works anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try AMDOverdriveCtrl:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/amdovdrvctrl/

Answer (score 1):

lsadl is only application i found that can overclock Radeon Mobility(require Catalyst driver), also it can change voltage:

Steps to install:

1. Download lsadl-0.1.2.tar.bz2 from http://freecode.com/projects/lsadl
2. Download ADL_SDK6 from http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/display-library-adl-sdk/
3. Extract lsadl-0.1.2.tar.bz2 to any folder (lsadl-0.1.2 in my case)
4. Create ADL_SDK folder in created folder and extract files from
       ALD_SDK_6.0.zip to it (lsadl-0.1.2/ADL_SDK in my case)
5. install `sudo apt-get install GTK+2`, `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, `sudo apt-get install autoconf`, `sudo apt-get install automake`
6. in terminal go to lsadl folder ( `cd '/home/gap/downloads/lsadl-0.1.2'` in my case)
7. `./autogen.sh`
8. `./configure && make`
9. run program `./lsadl`

Succesed with i3 2330m + radeon 6650m graph card on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: @MadMike: I believe, this is an attempt to answer the question. I don't see any new question in it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: I use google and can't found info that i needed for 3 days. This q&a is the first link that i opened, . I can create mine question and answer it myself if it really needed, just want to help people with same problem as i had. Edited post for more detailed info.

Comment: That looks much better. Thanks and have an upvote!